# libgdx AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing

Tags: android, libgdx

i'm extended libgdx in fragment my application, and i have problem.
If i open fragment:

```
         activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.objectSchemeView, GenerateBitmap.newInstnace(scheme))?.commit()
```

and press back from fragment -> and again open fragment, i'll get error:

```
E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

i search solution this problem, but developers framework deny the problem.

Someone has found a solution to this problem for fragment?

Code Adapter (TestModel - big json)

```
class Schema(var testModel: TestModel) : ApplicationAdapter() {
@Inject
lateinit var resource: IResourseProvider

internal lateinit var batch: SpriteBatch

private lateinit var texture: Texture
private lateinit var blackTexture: Texture
private lateinit var noneActive: Texture
private var sprites = LinkedHashMap<Sprite, PlaceItem>()
private var noneFreePlaces: ArrayList<PlaceItem> = ArrayList()

private lateinit var camera: OrthographicCamera
private lateinit var controller: CameraController

private lateinit var gestureDetector: GestureDetector

init {
    App.graph.inject(this)
}

override fun create() {
    batch = SpriteBatch()

    camera = OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.width.toFloat(), Gdx.graphics.height.toFloat())
    controller = CameraController()
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(20f, 0.5f, 2f, 0.15f, controller)
    Gdx.input.inputProcessor = gestureDetector

    val pixmap = Pixmap(30, 30, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
    pixmap.setColor(Color.BLACK)
    pixmap.fillCircle(10, 10, 10)
    texture = Texture(pixmap)

    pixmap.setColor(Color.BLACK)
    pixmap.fillCircle(10, 10, 10)
    blackTexture = Texture(pixmap)

    pixmap.setColor(Color.GRAY)
    pixmap.fillCircle(10, 10, 10)
    noneActive = Texture(pixmap)

    testModel.places?.forEach {
        when (getState(it.state)) {
            PlaceState.FREE -> {
                sprites.put(Sprite(Texture(pixmap)), it)
            }
            else -> {
                noneFreePlaces.add(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    controller.update()
    camera.update()
    batch.projectionMatrix = camera.combined
    batch.begin()

    for ((sprite, placeItem) in sprites) {
        sprite.setPosition(placeItem.x.toFloat(), placeItem.y.toFloat())
        batch.draw(sprite, placeItem.x.toFloat(), placeItem.y.toFloat())
    }

    noneFreePlaces.forEach {
        batch.draw(noneActive, it.x.toFloat(), it.y.toFloat())
    }

    batch.end()
}

override fun pause() {
    super.pause()
    for ((sprite, placeItem) in sprites) {
        sprite.texture.dispose()
    }
}

override fun dispose() {
    batch.dispose()
    texture.dispose()
    blackTexture.dispose()
    noneActive.dispose()
    for ((sprite, placeItem) in sprites) {
        sprite.texture.dispose()
    }
}

internal inner class CameraController : GestureDetector.GestureListener {
    private var velX: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var velY: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var flinging = false
    private var initialScale = 1f

    override fun touchDown(x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        flinging = false
        initialScale = camera.zoom
        return false
    }

    override fun tap(x: Float, y: Float, count: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        Gdx.app.log("GestureDetectorTest", "tap at $x, $y, count: $count")

        val touch = Vector3()
        camera.unproject(touch.set(x, y, 0f))

        for ((sprite, placeItem) in sprites) {
            if (sprite.boundingRectangle.contains(touch.x, touch.y)) {
                if (sprite.texture == blackTexture)
                    sprite.texture = texture
                else
                    sprite.texture = blackTexture
            }
        }


        return false
    }

    override fun longPress(x: Float, y: Float): Boolean {
        Gdx.app.log("GestureDetectorTest", "long press at $x, $y")
        return false
    }

    override fun fling(velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float, button: Int): Boolean {
        Gdx.app.log("GestureDetectorTest", "fling $velocityX, $velocityY")
        flinging = true
        velX = camera.zoom * velocityX * 0.5f
        velY = camera.zoom * velocityY * 0.5f
        return false
    }

    override fun pan(x: Float, y: Float, deltaX: Float, deltaY: Float): Boolean {
        // Gdx.app.log("GestureDetectorTest", "pan at " + x + ", " + y);
        camera.position.add(-deltaX * camera.zoom, deltaY * camera.zoom, 0f)
        return false
    }

    override fun panStop(x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        Gdx.app.log("GestureDetectorTest", "pan stop at $x, $y")
        return false
    }

    override fun zoom(originalDistance: Float, currentDistance: Float): Boolean {
        val ratio = originalDistance / currentDistance
        camera.zoom = initialScale * ratio
        println(camera.zoom)
        return false
    }

    override fun pinch(initialFirstPointer: Vector2, initialSecondPointer: Vector2, firstPointer: Vector2, secondPointer: Vector2): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    fun update() {
        if (flinging) {
            velX *= 0.98f
            velY *= 0.98f
            camera.position.add(-velX * Gdx.graphics.deltaTime, velY * Gdx.graphics.deltaTime, 0f)
            if (Math.abs(velX) < 0.01f) velX = 0f
            if (Math.abs(velY) < 0.01f) velY = 0f
        }
    }

    override fun pinchStop() {

    }
}
```

}

Code ApplicationFragment

```
class GenerateBitmap: AndroidFragmentApplication() {
private var glSurfaceView: GLSurfaceView? = null
private lateinit var model: TestModel
private lateinit var schema: Schema
private val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()

override fun onResume() {
    Gdx.input.isCatchBackKey = true
    Gdx.graphics.isContinuousRendering = true
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(resources.openRawResource((R.raw.example))))
    val mModel = Gson().fromJson<TestModel>(reader.readLine().toString(), TestModel::class.java)

    schema = Schema(mModel)
    return initializeForView(schema, config)
}

companion object {
    private val MODEL_KEY = "scheme"

    fun newInstnace(model: TestModel): GenerateBitmap {
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putSerializable(MODEL_KEY, model)

        val fragment = GenerateBitmap()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there some loop which is taking too long?

Comment: i'm added aditional code, he contains array of 5k elements.

Comment: Which array has 5k elements?

Comment: var noneFreePlaces: ArrayList<PlaceItem> = ArrayList() - contains 5k element and
sprites = LinkedHashMap<Sprite, PlaceItem>() - contains 50 elements

Comment: Can you do a log in every function to see which was the last function logged? Cuz I honestly do not know.

Comment: I did find something though https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2461